# Is it possible to make non-first tab selected in PySimpleGUI window startup?

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

```
window = sg.Window("foobar", layout, margins=(2, 2), finalize=True)
window.Element('-ENCR_TAB-').Select()
```

What I see is that the first tab is selected and only after a little while the '-ENCR_TAB-' (the second tab) is selected as expected. Is it possible to have it selected by default without such a delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no option about default selected tab, only work the way as you shown.

If there's any update or delay when window shown, IMO, you can move window out of screen before it ready, then move it back.

```py
location = sg.Window.get_screen_size()
window = sg.Window("foobar", layout, margins=(2, 2), location=location, finalize=True)
window['-ENCR_TAB-'].select()
window.refresh()
window.move_to_center()
```

Comment: Interesting trick; but, I still see it with `location` for a while in the center of the scren before it is moved to the bottom-right; I have dual monitors... The `location` is `3840, 1080`.

Comment: I don't have dual monitor, so know nothing about what the location value good for you. You can try to find the good value for it by yourself.

Comment: Hide the window. select, then unhide?

Comment: Or another trick is to create the window with parameter alpha_channel=0, then perform the operation, then set alpha=1.

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted by Jason is an excellent one.  Tkinter allows window `location` to be in areas that are not valid.  It could be `(10_000, 10_000)` in theory.  I'm not sure how long this unchecked error will continue to operate.

In case this becomes a problem, another approach is to use the Alpha Channel to hide the window.  Create the window with alpha set to zero.  This will make the window invisible.  Then you can perform operations without the user seeing them.  When done, set the alpha to 1 to make the window visible.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

tab1_layout = [[sg.Text('This is the layout for Tab 1')]]

tab2_layout = [[sg.Text('This is the layout for Tab 2')]]

tab_group_layout = [[sg.Tab('Tab 1', tab1_layout, key='-TAB1-'),
                     sg.Tab('Tab 2', tab2_layout, key='-TAB2-')]]

layout = [[sg.TabGroup(tab_group_layout, key='-TABGROUP-')],
          [sg.Exit()]]


window = sg.Window("Window with tabs", layout, margins=(2, 2), alpha_channel=0, finalize=True)
window['-TAB2-'].select()
window.set_alpha(1)
window.refresh()
event, values = window.read(close=True)
```